# ZURB-Foundation custom input is very slow

Tags: zurb-foundation

I'v'e tried using the custom dropdown from ZURB's Foundation.
It works when the number of options is small, but when I try to fit 250 countries in the list it freezes for multiple seconds when you choose an option.

Is my only option to use a standard select input?

Answer (score 0):

The Foundation's refreshCustomSelect() function is ridiculously slow.
As a workaround, after the custom select is created, you can use this code:

```
$('#country').attr('data-customforms', 'disabled');
```